# "Cannot resolve configuration property" in Spring boot when trying to configure probes

Tags: spring-boot, probe, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

In my `Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE` I'm tyring to enable to `readiness` and `liveness` endpoints.

I added this to the yml file:

[image]

But IntelliJ marks the values with "Cannot resolve configuration property" , and the endpoints are not accessible (e.g. http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project was missing the trivial dependency of the `actuator`:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

After adding it, the IntelliJ stopped complaining and the endpoints are accessible.